# Maths Equation Formatting - Brackets

Tags: math-mode, equations, brackets

Does anyone know how you would type this in latex?[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!! What have you tried so far? It is important for us to see your work using an MWE that you provide. Anyway, you could use `frac` and `cases` commands. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

The `amsmath` package is the go-to for typesetting maths in LaTeX. I would suggest reading an online tutorial to get a grasp of the basics - the [Mathematics](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics) page on the Wikibook and the [overleaf tutorial](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Mathematical_expressions) are good places to start.

As for the expression, a simple trick to produce a curly brace spanning several lines is to put those lines in an array and surround the array with the delimiters `\left\{` and `\right.` (the first prints the brace, the second nothing):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % Typsetting math in LaTeX

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*} % Unumbered equation environment for displayed math.
        \frac{GHQ_{T+2}}{GHQ_{\text{baselevel}}} % Fraction; note \text{} command for baselevel text
        = \left\{ % left deliminter
        \begin{array}{l} % Array with a single, Left-justified column
            > 1.15\\
            0.85 \leq 1.5\\
            <0.85\\
        \end{array}
        \right. % right deliminter (required)
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: example output png large]

Comment: Although the `cases` environment is probably better (see the duplicate for an example).